# Ant scp task error

Tags: ant, task, scp

I have a problem with my Ant scp task.
When I'm trying to send a file to a server, I get the follow error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: 2: No such file
```

Here is my task:

```
<scp verbose="yes"
 todir="${deploy.user}@${app.deploy.server}:/home/software/public_html/${app.appName}"
 password="${deploy.password}" sftp="true" trust="true" >
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/jnlp/extensions/production" includes="*.jnlp"/>
</scp>
```

Anyone have an idea about what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Certain Ant tasks, although standard tasks, require [third party libraries](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies). If you look at that table, you'll see that you need to install the [jsch.jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) version 0.142 or later.

Easiest thing to do is install this in `$ANT_HOME/lib`. That will solve your problem. However, it now creates an issue where you have a library dependency in your `build.xml` file that other users must be aware of. They'll have to know to manually install the required jar in their `$ANT_HOME/lib`, or define an `$ANT_LIB` directory and put it there.